# Google Charts - Color of gridlines for negative values on y-axis

Tags: google-visualization

I have a chart like this:
[image: Hi, I'm a chart!]
and I would like to change the color of Y-Axis grid lines below "0" so both -0.5 and -1.0 grid lines will become, for example, red.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

In your chart.draw/ options call, add: 
vAxis:{viewWindow: {min: 0}}